# Using cowboy_static to serve gzip compressed files

Tags: erlang, cowboy

We are using cowboy version 1.0.3 and we would like to serve compressed gzip versions of our files. We set the flag as noted in the documentation:

```
{compress, true}
```

But we notice that files served by the `cowboy_static` module are not being compressed, do we need to set up our own handler for this or are we missing something ?

Comment: I think you need to provide some `Extra` check this link for more info http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/manual/cowboy_static/#_types

Comment: From the docs: "Extra options allow you to define how the etag should be calculated and how the mimetype of files should be detected". How can that help me with the compression ?